# Downgrade Apache Server 2.4.6 to 2.2.x on RHEL7

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, httpd

I have a Apache Web Server 2.4.6 setup running on RHEL7 box.
I was trying to setup user authentication to the site hosted in Apache Server by installing and configuring Siteminder WebAgent version 12.5.

After doing all necessary configuration, on restarting httpd, I get following error -

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 61 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /root/CA/webagent/bin/libmod_sm22.so into server: /root/CA/webagent/bin/libmod_sm22.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
```

After much debugging I realized that there are version incompatibility issues and although WebAgent installer detects apache server version correctly and says installation is successful but change in Apache Server API in 2.4 version leads to failure.

Also from CA SiteMinder site I got to know that they don't support RHEL7 yet.
So only option I am left is to downgrade apache server from 2.4.x to 2.2.x.

I am not sure how that can be done, can anyone help me out with it?

One simple way would be to get the source code compile and deploy but is there some way to do it via yum?

**Adding Update**
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257856/how-do-i-install-an-older-version-of-apache-httpd-in-centos-6-using-yum

From above link I found a way to do it using yum, but I am not sure if it will preserve the settings/configurations done earlier, I believe source code based installation would be right choice.

Comment: I am able to set it up using source code, pls ignore the question, I will delete or post the answer once I am able to setup and verify everything